# Floating point operation returns different result in PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php

I get different results when try to division same numbers in PHP and C#:

PHP:

```
echo 1000/0.03475; 
output:28776.9784173
```

C#:

```
1000/0.03475
output:28776,9784172662
```

Why? And how to get same results?

Comment: I'd say they were the same result personally.

Comment: different languages/libraries use different algorithms/code. So it's no surprise the floating point values differ at some precision. The issue is more likely how the results are being displayed.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Isn't the point of a standard (here: IEEE Standard 754) that all implementations yield the same result?

Comment: @dtb: The standard defines formats and some rounding algorithms. Not all languages follow that standard

Comment: If everything actually followed standards...

Comment: Use ini_set('precision',16) to set the precision used for displaying numbers in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But they do give the very same result, just rounded to different numbers of decimal places when displayed. If you were to look at the actual bits representing the floating-point number in memory, they ought to be identical (given the same architecture).

Answer (score 1):

What the other answers say is probably the reason you have different values (more accurately, different rounding in display).

However, in PHP a float as the same semantincs a C `double` (it usually has 64 bits) has (additionally, PHP targets C89, while [only C99 defined floating point arithmetic so that it complies with IEEE 754](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI_Compilers_and_Industry_Standards#IEEE_754)):

> The C89 standard does not even require IEEE format, and for C99, full IEEE 754 support (Inf, NaN, denormals) is optional.

In C# a `float` is [32-bit wide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(VS.71).aspx) and is guaranteed to be (mostly) IEEE 754 compliant. The closest thing to PHP's float would be C# [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how they're being displayed.

```
printf("%.10f\n", 1000 / 0.03475);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities, as others have said: either they're the same floating-point value, but just printing differently, or they're different floating-point values. To see if they're the same, you need to print all the decimal digits -- if your language allows (C# and PHP don't -- see my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-dyadic-fractions-varies-by-language/).

They could be different floating-point values because not all compilers/interpreters/run-time libraries convert every decimal string to the correct floating-point number (in your example, I'm talking about the 0.03475 part in particular). See my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/incorrectly-rounded-conversions-in-visual-c-plus-plus/ for more details.